# I need help to use a python code to find the sum of numbers between two integers that were inputted

Tags: python, sum

I need help to use python code to find the sum of numbers between two integers that were inputted.

I have included my code so far below but it doesn't seem to work.

```
num1 = int(input('What is your first number? '))
num2 = int(input('What is your second number? '))
if num1 > num2:
    high = num1
    low = num2
if num1 < num2:
    low = num1
    high = num2
def main():
    sum = low
    low = low + 1
    sum = low + sum
    if low > high:
        print('The sum is', sum)
    if low < high:
        main()
```

The question is below:

> Consider an algorithm that takes 2 integers and finds the sum of all the integers between them (including the two numbers).
>
> For example, the numbers 2 and 5 give a sum of 14.
>   2 + 3 + 4 + 5 = 14

Comment: is the indentation of the question given here correct? if yes, when do you see the function named `main` being actually called in the code?

Comment: Hi, as I'm quite new to coding I put def main(): above the sum = low part if that's what you meant.

Comment: @Anthony `def main()` is _defining_ the function. To _run_ the function, you need `main()` somewhere else in your code.

Comment: a function is "defined" using the def keyword. defining the function never actually executes or runs it. (It is like putting a few lines of code together and giving them a name.) you have to "call" the function after defining it. For example, by writing `main()`. But the calling has to be outside the function definition.

Comment: Python has a list of in-built functions to make  life of programmers easy. For eg, the whole code you have written is just `sum(range(num1, num2+1))`. To understand what this does, I suggest you start from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def main(num1, num2):
    sum = 0
    if num2 > num1:
        for i in range(num1, num2+1):
            sum += i
    elif num1 > num2:
        for i in range(num2, num1+1):
            sum += i
    else: sum = num1*2
    return sum


num1 = int(input('What is your first number? '))
num2 = int(input('What is your second number? '))
sum = main(num1, num2)
print('The sum is:', sum)
```

Read line by line and it will make sense :) Good luck

Comment: apart from having no explanation for someone who is clearly new to programming, this fails in cases where num2 is smaller than num1.

Comment: I fixed it. Good luck my friend!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest approach would be to use the built-in `sum` function over a `range` from `low` to `high`. Note the ranges exclude the upper barrier, so you'd have to increment it to include the inputted `high` value:

```
sum_between = sum(range(low, high + 1))
```

A more performant approach (at least for large ranges) would probably be to use the [formula for a sum of an arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum):

```
n = high - low + 1
sum_between = n * (low + high) / 2
```

Answer (score 1):

you can remove the `for-loop` entirely. just use Python built-in tools, for your target, use `sum(range(num1,num2+1))`, your check that `num1>num2` or `num1<num2` are correct, and please keep them in the code, but you have one unhandle case : when they are equal, and at that case you just return `sum = num1`.

hope it helped